# I'm trying to validate some code to get only 0-100 and no letters

Tags: java, validation

Below is the code that I have but I keep getting the messages

> The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) Scanner, int,

or

> The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) Scanner, int.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Num {
    public static void main(String arg[]){

        int grade = 0;
        Scanner score = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean testNum = false;

        while(testNum == false){
            if(score >= 0 && score <= 100){
                System.out.println("Enter in the test grade.");
                grade = score.nextInt();
                testNum = true;
            } else if(!score.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry.");
                score.next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can something be simultaneous less then 0 and greater then 100?

Comment: `score.nextInt()` will give you the integer entered as user input.

Answer (score 4):

> The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) Scanner, int,
>   or The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) Scanner

You should compare `int` input given to the scanner and not scanner directly with `int` values.

```
if(score <= 0 && score >= 100){//Incorrect : score is your scanner Object
```

---

```
//Add if condition to check whether scanner has int input by #hasNextInt
int input = score.nextInt();//Collect int input
if(input <= 0 && input >= 100){//compare it to check whether it's between 0-100
```

Comment: I understand that but I am still confused on validating no strings. Can you help me understand that?

Answer (score 1):

you should be using java.util.Scanner.next() method to get next input and store it to some variable then use that variable to compare. Even your if block is also seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not taking any number from user, you are just comparing Scanner object with a numeric value.
2. You have to take user input by doing:

   i) score.nextInt() OR 
   ii) firstArg = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // From System args[]

Once you have an initial numeric value, you can code your loop logic.

Answer (score -2):

The reason you are getting error is that the score variable is not an integer and you are trying >= and <=. Try with > and < operator.

Comment: What good will that do? Then he will get the error: "The operator **`<`** is undefined for the argument type(s) Scanner, int," instead of "The operator **`<=`** is undefined for the argument type(s) Scanner, int,"...